# What is the recommended method to call a Oracle MCS API?

Tags: oracle-jet, mcs

I used to call MCS API in the similar way as Rest API is called .Is it is recommended method or I have to use Cordova SDK to integrate Oracle MCS with my mobile Application

Answer (score 0):

You're free to choose either.  The reason Oracle provide the SDKs is to cut down on the amount of code you have to write yourself in your client, and in turn provide a well tested solution.  Personally I find the setup of the SDK simple and saves me from having to learn all the details of the REST APIs.  But if you're comfortable working at that level, go for it.

Disclaimer: I work for Oracle.